# How can I get heap info from another process in c++?

Tags: c++, .net, memory, process, heap-memory

I am trying to use an external c++ program to track the heap info in my another program. I've looked into functions like this:

GetProcessHeaps()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee175820(v=vs.85).aspx

But it only works for the calling process, not an external process. How do I get the detailed heap informaion from anthoer process (not just size), like HeapMemView, in c++?

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/heap_memory_view.html

And if possible and even better, how to do it with .Net?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3313700/179910).

Comment: Thank you very much! Oh how do I find this function without stackoverflow!?

Comment: VirtualQueryEx, not ReadProcessMemory :P

Comment: More questions: I can get the virtual memory info from VirtualQueryEx(), but how do I get the heap information?

Comment: I suppose if you want to badly enough, you can create a DLL that uses GetProcessHaps, HeapWalk, etc., and then inject that DLL into the target process. I suspect there are good reasons this isn't more directly supported though.