# Memory dump of external process

Tags: c++, winapi

I am attempting to read and write data to external processes, but the `ReadProcessMemory()` function has a lot of inputs I am unfamiliar with:

```
BOOL WINAPI ReadProcessMemory(
  _In_   HANDLE hProcess,
  _In_   LPCVOID lpBaseAddress,
  _Out_  LPVOID lpBuffer,
  _In_   SIZE_T nSize,
  _Out_  SIZE_T *lpNumberOfBytesRead
);
```

I figured out how to get the handle using `OpenProcess()`, but how do I know the `lpBaseAddress` is? I want to dump the entire thing, so a `for` loop with `ReadProcessMemory()` being called at four byte intervals should run, but from what to what? I don't know where the process is in RAM, or how large the process is (to know when the for loop ends). What functions should I use to extract that data?

Comment: I guess this isn't quite an exact duplicate, but most (if not all) of what you seem to want is covered in a couple of my older answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10373209/179910, and: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10373209/179910

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm attempting the dissect the code you answer with on the question, but I'll mention that both the links you posted are identical, so I'm assuming you meant to put another one of your answers there.

Comment: Oops. Sorry 'bout that. One of the links should have been to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3313700/179910

Comment: If you want to dump an external process use [`MiniDumpWriteDump`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx) instead. `ReadProcessMemory` is going to give you a headache - a process' memory is usually not a single, contiguous block of memory.

Comment: @IInspectable That's a valid answer, why don't you post it?

Comment: @IInspectable If you post MiniDumpWriteDump and how to use it with example (It says you need PROCESS_VM_READ and other stuff, so how to gain those permissions would be great), I would definitely accept the answer.

Comment: Since you write that you want to read and **write** data to another process I didn't post the comment as an answer. You may also be expecting that `MiniDumpWriteDump` gives you the memory contents to be readily readable. This is not the case. `.dmp` files are to be consumed by debuggers (like WinDbg) for inspection. If you provide more succinct information of what you are essentially trying to achieve you are likely to get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read MSDN's documentation on [ReadProcessMemory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) which will explain to you each argument.

```
lpBaseAddress = a pointer to the address where you want to begin reading
lpbuffer = a pointer to a buffer you create to store the data you read
nSize = the size of your buffer, use sizeof(buffer)
lpNumberOfBytesRead = a pointer to another buffer which will store the number
of bytes which were successfully read, this is good for error checking
```

Here is some code that will effectively read all memory into a buffer in iterations, you can then do whatever you want with the data in the buffer.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;
    char* addr = 0;

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

    char buffer[0x1000];

    while (VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
    {
        if (mbi.State != MEM_COMMIT || mbi.Protect == PAGE_NOACCESS)
        {
            char* buffer = new char[mbi.RegionSize];

            ReadProcessMemory(hProc, addr, buffer, mbi.RegionSize, nullptr);
        }
        addr += mbi.RegionSize;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProc);
}
```

This is not a perfect method but good enough for most uses.