# How can I get private working set of the process on C++ language

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get private working set of the process. I've used `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` method for this purpose and couldn't retrieve private working set from `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS` or `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` structures. I tried to use
`WorkingSetSize` field of `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` structure, but this field's value is equal to the sum of  Shareable and Private working sets. Is it possible to get only Shareable or Private working set of the process on C++ language?

Here is the code I use:

```
PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX processMem;

if (GetProcessMemoryInfo(::GetCurrentProcess(), (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS *)&processMem, sizeof(processMem))) {
    SIZE_T processRam = processMem.WorkingSetSize;
}
```

Also, I tried to get `processMem.PrivateUsage` field, but this value isn't equal to my process' private working set size.

Comment: Please show your actual code, the actual structure values being reported, etc.

Comment: You could use `VirtualQuery` or `VirtualQueryEx` to retrieve data about memory blocks individually, then sum up the pieces you want. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3313700/179910

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need this information?

Comment: How do you know that the value you got isn't equal to your process' private wss? What tool(?) did you use to get that value?