# C# .NET reading all of of a process troubles

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I'm messing around with a scanning engine I'm working on and I'm trying to read the memory of a process. My code is below (it's a little messy) but for some reason if I read the memory of an application in different states, or after it has a lot of things loaded into memory, I get the same memory size no matter what. Are my entry point addresses and length incorrect?

If I use a memory editor I don't get the same results I do with this.

```
        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)[0];
        List<Byte[]> moduleMemory = new List<byte[]>();

        byte[] temp;

            //MessageBox.Show(pm.FileName);
            temp = new byte[pm.ModuleMemorySize];
            int read;

            if (ReadProcessMemory(process.Handle, pm.BaseAddress, temp, temp.Length, out read)) {
                moduleMemory.Add(temp);
            }
        }
        //string d = Encoding.Default.GetString(moduleMemory[0]);
        MessageBox.Show("Size: " + moduleMemory[0].Length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probaly caused by the fact, that `Process` class [caches values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks):

> The process component obtains information about a group of properties
>   all at once. After the Process component has obtained information
>   about one member of any group, it will cache the values for the other
>   properties in that group and not obtain new information about the
>   other members of the group until you call the Refresh method.
>   Therefore, a property value is not guaranteed to be any newer than the
>   last call to the Refresh method. The group breakdowns are
>   operating-system dependent.

Therefore after target process loads some additional modules, `process` instance will still return old values. Calling `process.Refresh()` should update all cached values and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As I see this code does nothing more than reading the memory layout of the executable module (.exe file) which the process was created for. So no wonder you get the same size all the time.

I assume you are up to read the "operational" memory of the process. If so, you should have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313581/runtime-process-memory-patching-for-restoring-state/).